# Help required in customizing HTML text in tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Here is what I am stuck with...

I am formatting a a text with Richtext Editor in TinyMCE. Whenever i mark any text to bold, the html generated puts that text in <strong> tag, and likewise for Underline, a <span> tag with style=text-decoration attributes and for Italics <em> tag. Also if I modify the text size, still it puts a <span> with style=font-size attribute.

Now what i need is I want this text to get converted into basic HTML with <b> <u> <i> for Bold, Underline and Italics, respectively, and also for font size change or coloring etc, i want a <font> tag with standard attrtibutes (color, size etc.)

One way i feel would work is to modify the tiny_mce.js Register default formats.

But, i fear that it might invoke some regression issues with my other code modules.

Is that the solution for the problem, or is there any better way, maybe some configuration option to change this...

Any pointers for this shall be appreciated!

Thanks,

Mangirish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the approch Sascha Galley proposed you will need to activate the legacyoutput plugin in your tinymce init:

```
plugins: "...,code,save,legacyoutput,...",
```

Comment: @Tharima... You are right, I was just about to post that as the answer if i had not seen yours, already here. I used the legacyoutput plugin with some tweeks in its js file to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own formats, have a look at the documentation: [TinyMCE formats](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aformats). In your case it would be something like:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    formats : {
        bold : {inline : 'b'},
        italic : {inline : 'i'},
        underline : {inline : 'u'},
    }
});
```

I have not tested it but this should lead you into the right direction.

Comment: Hi Sascha, Thanks for your inputs but unfortunately it still doesn't work with this solution. the strong, em tags do not vanish... :(